# Broken pipe | Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

When upgrading packages I get a broken pipe error:

```
Package lists are read... Done
Dependency tree is created... Done
Status information is read in... Done
Try "apt --fix-broken install" to correct this.
The following packages have unfulfilled dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends on: libnode72 (= 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.3) but 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.4 is installed
          Recommends: nodejs-doc
E: Unfulfilled dependencies. Try "apt --fix-broken install" without specifying a package (or specify a solution).
```

I tried `apt --fix-broken install` and also removing `nodejs libnode72` but it couldn't even do that cause of dependency errors.

Appreciate all help.

Comment: @user535733 I aded the complete output.

Comment: @karel Sadly not. I tried the options mentioned there but the error remains the same.